# Phantomjs / Casper won't render <embed> inside an <iframe>

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm working on this test where I have to get the contents of a pdf file. The html structure (after rendering on client side on a traditional browser) is something like this

```
<iframe id="frame" name="frame" src="a link" id="frame" >
   <embed id="plugin" src="src to pdf file">
        pdf shows up here
   </embed
</iframe>
```

When I output the html on casper the iframe contents is empty, my code is something like this

```
casper.then(function(){
    this.wait(5000);
    casper.withFrame('frame', function(){
       //the page renders whell but it won't show the pdf
       this.capture('pic.png');
       this.evaluate(function(){
           //finds
           document.querySelector('body');
           //returns null
           document.querySelector('embed');
       });
    });
);
```

I don't understand why phantom won't render the  element with the pdf file, is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to give you an in-depth answer because you did not provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). However, I can suggest you several things to solve your problem:

### 1. Fix syntax errors

There are a couple of syntax errors in your code, especially when you use `evaluate`. The callback is not passed properly and you do not return any value. To test `evaluate` results, you generally have to do something like this:

```
this.echo('Title: ' + this.evaluate(function () {
  return document.title;
}));
```

### 2. Use `getHTML()` to check if `<embed>` is present

Inside `withFrame`, you could print the raw HTML code of the `<iframe>` with this line:

```
console.log(this.getHTML());
```

This is what CasperJS is actually seeing.

### 3. Test this script and analyze the output carefully

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('URL OF YOUR MAIN PAGE');

casper.then(function () {
  this.echo('Main page: ' + this.getTitle());
  this.wait(5000).withFrame('frame', function () {
    this.echo('iframe: ' + this.evaluate(function () {
      return document.title;
    }));
    this.capture('pic.png');
    console.log(this.getHTML());
  });
});

casper.run();
```